# Pagination on apache-cassandra data base management system table

Tags: java

I am using apache-cassandra data base management system with version 3.11.14. It contains transaction table with millions of records. I want to apply pagination so created an end point for pagination. While implementing came to know that it's not supported for backward direction (previous) in pagination. How to apply pagination with quick response time and both previous and next page support in Java spring-boot?

I have created a point as mentioned below.

```
@GetMapping("/pagination")
Pagination<T> getPageOfTransactions(@RequestParam("size") int size) {

}
```

Used repository Slice<T> findAll(Pageable pageable) method.

Its only supporting forward direction. I am expecting pagination on transaction on table which should be called from backend endpoint. It should return PaginationResponse which contains List<T> transactions, boolean hasMore, String nextCursor as parameters. When user clicking on page number it should fetch records in quick responsive time. If not feasible at least with Previous and Next buttons from UI.